# Docker compose volumes gcc compilation time is super slow

Tags: docker, gcc, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, volumes

I set up a docker with a docker-compose to compile some c code.
The idea is to use it with vsCode devcontainers.

I have two problems:
1. With the Docker-compose-1 the compilation is fast but the git inside vsCode dev container sees all the files under sdk as modified.
2. If I use Docker-compose-2 the compilation is super slow but git is ok in vsCode dev container.

I guess the first problem has to do with how the volumes work in docker but why the compilation is so much slower in the second scenario?

Ideal would be to be able to use git from devcontainer and also have a reasonable time of compilation.

I also tried to add a .dockerignore with sdk but didn't help either.

Any idea or tips would be very much appreciated!

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Best regards

```
# Dockerfile
FROM gcc:9.3
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
```

```
# Docker-compose-1
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
      - sdk:/code/sdk

volumes:
  sdk:
```

```
compilation time is:
  real    0m15.448s
  user    0m6.331s
  sys     0m2.137s
```

```
# Docker-compose-2
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
      - ./sdk:/code/sdk
```

```
compilation time with Docker-compose-2 is:
  real    2m23.196s
  user    0m6.862s
  sys     0m10.658s
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Volumes on MacOS are [known to be slow](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap) and you're probably hitting that.  Why do you need to run the compiler inside a container?

Comment: Thank you. To have it more portable, I don't want to deal with the configuration for every single computer. In this way, I know once it's done, everything works, all the paths are correct, plus is easy for someone new to just make it run. Also, I prefer keeping my OS clean

Comment: By the way, the problem with git in the first configuration seems to be due to an older version that I was doing tests with. I had to delete the volume. Now I do COPY in docker and seems to work nicely. The problem I have now is that, if I change something on sdk from devcontainer it is not reflected in git? any idea if I can make it go two ways?